# How to compute the sum $\sum_{k=100}^{200} 5\cdot 2^k $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

$$\sum_{k=100}^{200} 5\cdot2^k $$

If the question was this:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{10} 5\cdot2^k $$

then I would have just plugged in the number $8$ times. Since this has a larger range, it wouldn't be a good idea of plugging in the number $100$ times. Is there any better and useful way I can use to solve this question?

Comment: Have you seen  the formula for a geometric sum? Review that!

Comment: Your second sigma doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big hint:

$$ \sum_{k=a}^b q \cdot r^k = q \cdot \frac{r^a - r^{b+1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: By using the formula I ended up getting the following value: 1.606928e+61

Comment: I just want to make sure..if its right or wrong. Can you tell me please

Comment: @user372204, yeah, that sounds right.  It's a pretty massive number.

Comment: @user372204, yep, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Let $q, q^2, q^3....$ be a geometric sequence. then any sum of consecutive terms of this sequence is given by

$S=$first term of $S.\frac{1-q^N}{1-q}$ where $N$ is the number of terms in $S$.

thus

$$\sum_{k=100}^{200}2^k=$$

$$2^{100}\frac{1-2^{101}}{1-2}=$$

$$2^{201}-2^{100}.$$

to finish, multiply by $5$.